# Normalizr usage for deep nested obj

Tags: json, ngrx, normalizr

I am trying to use Normalizr for normalize and denormalize object that I am using within my angular ngrx app.

I found almost the solution for it here:https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1028240/Deep-nested-tree-normalize-with-normaliz

```
import {normalize, Schema, arrayOf} from 'normalizr';

var data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "О компании",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Руководство",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Генеральный директор",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 20,
                                "name": "Зам гендира"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 8,
                                "name": "Секретарша"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "Главный бухгалтер",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 21,
                                "name": "Зам главбуха"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Вакансии",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Фронтенд-разработчик (JS)"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Бэкэнд-разработчик (Java)"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Оператор ЭВМ"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The thing is that many functions from solution below changed and it is little bit hard for me to use same solution with newer release of normalizr. Maybe some of you know how to rewrite below solution into new normalizr?

```
var node = new Schema('nodes');
node.define({
    children: arrayOf(node)
});
var treeSchema = arrayOf(node);


var normalizedData = normalize(data, treeSchema);
console.log(normalizedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at an example using an outdated version of Normalizr. Try reading [the docs](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md) for new APIs

Answer (score 0):

I did it :)

```
 const node = new schema.Entity('nodes');
    node.define({
        children: [node]
    })
    const treeSchema = [node];
    const normalizedData = normalize(this.form,treeSchema);
```